Children's book about a boy travelling in space with a wolverine
Looking for a book about a boy travelling in space with a wolverine.  That is all I can remember.  Read in the 1960s, so could be written in, I would guess, the 1950s or 1960s.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Andre Norton's Storm Over Warlock has wolverines, but it takes place on the world of Warlock. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_Over_Warlock

Thank you very much i think this may be it!
